# Custom Apache SSHD server messages not displayed by Filezilla, WinSCP and Psftp.exe

Tags: ssh

I am setting up a custom SSH server using Apache SSHD which interacts with web services, and depending on the web service response the file will be stored or discarded.

Following is my use case:

All users have some limits to upload file into the system.

If user tries to upload a file, I am hitting web service to find the user limits under SSH_FXP_WRITE [6].  If limit exceeds, I am sending SSH_FX_FAILURE and my custom message back to the clients.

The clients are discarding the custom message that I  send and just showing the following error:

```
Error:  error while writing: failure
Error:  File transfer failed
```

Is there anything that I need to configure at client side or is there any specific message that I need to send so that clients will start displaying the messages.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any VPN connection that is open concurrently? We found that to be the case with ours. Disconnect the VPN connection and try again.